# What is Nutch 1.10 crawl command for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, command, web-crawler, nutch

Using Nutch 1.10 (newbie), I am trying to learn how to crawl using Nutch 1.10 and using ElasticSearch as my indexer. Not sure why, but I can not get this crawl command to work:

```
bin/crawl -i --elastic -D elastic.server.url=http://localhost:9200/elastic/ urls elasticTestCrawl 1
```

UPDATE: just used

```
bin/crawl -i -D elastic.server.url=http://localhost:9200/elastic/ urls/ elasticTestCrawl/  2
```

--almost succesfully, received following error when it came to the indexing part of the command:

```
Error running:
  /home/david/apache-nutch-1.10/bin/nutch clean -Delastic.server.url=http://localhost:9200/elastic/ elasticTestCrawl//crawldb
Failed with exit value 255.
```

What is exit value 255 for nutch 1.x? And why does the space get deleted between "-D and elastic..."

I have these ElasticSearch Properties from [here](https://www.mind-it.info/integrating-nutch-1-7-elasticsearch/) in my nutch-site.xml file:

If someone can point my to the error of my ways, that would be great!

**Update**
I just posted my own answer below, its the second one. I had already accepted the first answer months ago when I initially got it working. My answer is simply more clear and concise to make it easier (and quicker) to get started with Nutch.

Comment: How to solve this failed with exit value 255 error ? I'm running into same issue

Comment: @Sachin use this command in your cli: bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:9300/elastic/ urls/ TestCrawl/  2  - You have to pay attention to localhost part (change port and solr parts). Click on and read the first link in Working Update above to get a feel and then try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't tell you where you're going wrong as I'm in the same boat although from what I can see you are running nutch and elastic on the same box where as I've split it across two.

I've not got it to work but according to a guide I found on integrating nutch 1.7 with elastic it should just be

```
bin/crawl urls/ TestCrawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

It may just be it isn't working for me because I've added the extra complication of networking.

I also assume you have created an index called elasticTestIndex in your elastic instance and launched it on the box before trying to run your crawl?

Should it be of help the guide I got that command from is

https://www.mind-it.info/integrating-nutch-1-7-elasticsearch/

**Update:**

I'm not sure I'm quite there yet but using your update I've got further than I had.

You are putting in port 9200 which is the web administartion port but you need to use port 9300 to interact with the service so change the port to 9300

I'm not sure but I thing the portion after the slash refers to the index so in your example make sure you have "elastic" set up as an index. or change

```
blah (low rep score so can't put in to many urls) blah localhost:9300/[index name]/
```

so that it uses and index you have created. If you haven't created one then you can do so from the putty with the following command.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/[index name]/'
```

Using the command you supplied with the alternative port it did run although I've yet to extract the crawl data from elastic.

**Supplemental Update:**

It's successfully dumping data crawled from nutch into elastic for me and having put a different index in on the command line I can tell you it ignores that and uses what ever is in your nutch-site.xml

Comment: the port thing was something I was trying, I changed it to 9200 to see if it would help get things working. May have forgotten if you didn't say anything, so thanks!

Comment: the [index name] name is a good heads up - I think your onto something there

Comment: check out my Working Update up top - hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**To help anyone else get it working**

Start off by reading this [blog post](https://www.mind-it.info/2013/09/26/integrating-nutch-1-7-elasticsearch/) to help you get Elasticsearch configured to work with Nutch.

After that read [this Nutch doc](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) to get familiar with the **NEW** cli command for running the crawl script. (Works for 1.9+)

Follow the example in the new Nutch crawl script command on that page. You have to change it a bit for elasticsearch:
solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ to something like
elastic.server.url=http://localhost:9300/yourelasticindex/

So basically there are 2 steps:

1. Configure Elasticsearch to work with Nutch (click on first link above)
2. Change the new cli command for solr to work with Elasticsearch (its
   default is solr) Hope that helps!